Percentage for each row count in Mixpanel JQL
I have issue with having percentage of the count of each API compared to total count of APIs.
i've had challenges through Mixpanel JQL to reach this purpose, i used reducer also.
now i've got that each item, always carries the data of that specific 'api_endpoint', so does this mean that i can never have percentage of each API in a column in front of 'Counts' column?
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2024-08-01',
    to_date:   '2024-08-15'
  })
  .filter(function(event) {
    return event.name === "api_response" && event.properties.api_response_type === "success";
  })
  .groupBy(['properties.api_endpoint'], mixpanel.reducer.count())
  .map(function(item) {
    var apiName = item.key[0];
     
    return {
      "API Name": apiName,
      "Counts": item.value
    };
  });
}

My expectation is to have this :



API Name
Counts
Percentage




api_name_01
8
20.51%


api_name_02
13
33.33%


api_name_03
3
7.69%


api_name_04
9
23.07%


api_name_05
6
15.38%




I fixed it by using only 'reduce' after 'groupBy' and not 'map'.
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2024-08-01',
    to_date:   '2024-08-15'
  })
  .filter(function(event) {
    return event.name === "api_response";
  })
  .groupBy(['properties.api_endpoint'], mixpanel.reducer.count())
  .reduce(function(acu, events) {
    var total = events.reduce(function(acu, item) {
      return acu += item.value
    }, 0)
    
    var generateApiName = function(endpoint) {
      return endpointToName[endpoint] || endpoint
    }
    
    var generatePercentage = function(apiCount) {
      var percNum = (apiCount * 100) / total
      
      return `${parseFloat(percNum.toFixed(2))}%`;
    };
    
    var modifiedEvents = events.map(function(event) {
      var endpoint = generateApiName(event.key[0]);
      var counts = event.value;
      var percentage = generatePercentage(counts)
      
      return {
        "API Name": endpoint,
        Counts: counts,
        Percentage: percentage
      }
    })
    
    return modifiedEvents
  });
}

I've got that in a whole reduce, we have access to filtered and grouped events all at once, therefore we can generate the data in a way we want.
